# np.diff() giving incorrect output when used on a array from an image

Tags: arrays, numpy, diff

I have a np.array created from reading an image.
I am interested in creating the difference between alternate pixel values. Hence I did the slicing as below.

```
roi_pixels = np.array(cropped_image[-250:, -1280:])
roi_pixels_even = roi_pixels[::,::2]
roi_pixels_odd = roi_pixels[::,1::2]
```

However, when I do np.diff on these arrays, I don't get the difference properly. The differences are calculated a huge numbers whenever the difference i negative (pic of the difference shown below). I have highlighted only 3 values but there are many many more (all values upward of 60K).

However, when I create an brand new array with these values like below & use the np.diff() method, everything come fine!!! can anyone help why I don't get it properly in the array I create from the image?

```
x = np.array([1545, 1661, 1782, 1992, 1899, 1981, 1980, 1974, 2049, 2033, 2059,
        2049, 2009, 1925, 1710, 1725, 1715, 1643, 1454, 1289,  979,  676,
         649,  637,  715,  763,  787,  769,  788,  822])

If I use abs(np.diff(x)), output is as below
array([116, 121, 210,  93,  82,   1,   6,  75,  16,  26,  10,  40,  84,
       215,  15,  10,  72, 189, 165, 310, 303,  27,  12,  78,  48,  24,
        18,  19,  34]

If I use np.diff(x), output is as below
array([ 116,  121,  210,  -93,   82,   -1,   -6,   75,  -16,   26,  -10,
        -40,  -84, -215,   15,  -10,  -72, -189, -165, -310, -303,  -27,
        -12,   78,   48,   24,  -18,   19,   34])
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like the first set of results are an unsigned dtype. unit16 would return greater than 32768 for negative numbers. What dtypes are the roi_pixel... arrays?

Comment: roi_pixel array is of datatype `dtype('uint16')` & you are right. That seems to be the problem. What i change the datatype with `r = roi_pixels_even.astype(int)` & then do `r.diff()`, i get the correct answers! Thank you very much. If you can put this as an answer, I will accept & up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.diff` returns an array of the same dtype as the input array.  If this is an unsigned dtype negative integers will have their bit pattern converted into the uint dtype resulting in high integers.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
arr = np.random.randint( 2000, size = 10, dtype = np.uint16)

arr
# array([1544,  796,  792,  976, 1859, 1859, 1895,  379, 1879, 1197], dtype=uint16)

np.diff(arr)  # arr has dtype uint16
# array([64788, 65532,   184,   883,     0,    36, 64020,  1500, 64854], dtype=uint16)
# The result has dtype uint16 

signed = arr.astype( np.int16 )  # signed has dtype int16 ( a signed type )
np.diff( signed )
# array([ -748,    -4,   184,   883,     0,    36, -1516,  1500,  -682], dtype=int16)
# The result has dtype int16
```

The relationship between signed and unsigned versions of int16 can be seen below.

```
# Take dif as int32 of np.diff( signed )
dif = np.diff( signed ).astype( np.int32 )
dif[ dif < 0 ] += 0x10000  # 2 ** 16 in hex
# Add 2 ** 16 to any negative results
dif
# array([64788, 65532,   184,   883,     0,    36, 64020,  1500, 64854])

# dif == np.diff( arr )
( dif == np.diff(arr) ).all()
# True
```